# ASP.NET Core 3.1 SignalR: method not being called

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, signalr, auth0

I have an app that is React on the front end and nodejs on the backend. I have decided to rewrite the back end in ASP.NET Core 3.1 using SignalR. I am new to both ASP.NET Core 3.1 and SignalR, and so I am having a little difficulty identifying the cause of the problem I am having.

The problem is that the hub method that I am calling from the front end is not being hit. I followed [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-3.1) a few days ago and managed to get the hub method to be called, but since introducing a few features, such as JWT authentication [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1), and MongoDB, the method is now not being called. I cannot work out why!

The connection appears to be successful considering the logs output in the browser.

My `startup.cs` looks like this:

```
namespace MpApp.API
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddCors(options =>
      {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
          builder =>
          {
            builder
              .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3010")
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowCredentials();
          });
      });

      var domain = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/";
      services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
          options.Authority = domain;
          options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];

          options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
          {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
              var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

              // If the request is for our hub...
              var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                  (path.StartsWithSegments("/chathub")))
              {
                // Read the token out of the query string
                context.Token = accessToken;
              }

              return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
          };
        });

      services.AddAuthorization(options =>
      {
        options.AddPolicy("read:messages",
          policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("read:messages", domain)));
      });

      services.AddControllers();

      services.AddSignalR();

      // Register the scope authorization handler
      services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasScopeHandler>();

      Debug.WriteLine("===== about to init config =====");
      services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(
        Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseSettings)));

      services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
        sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseSettings>>().Value);

      services.AddSingleton<IBaseService, BaseService>();

      services.AddSingleton<CollectionService<Profile>>();
      services.AddSingleton<CollectionService<User>>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      else
      {
        app.UseHsts();
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

and my `ChatHub.cs` looks like this:

```
namespace MyApp.API.Hubs
{
  public class ChatHub : Hub
  {
    protected CollectionService<Profile> _profileService;
    protected CollectionService<User> _userService;

    public ChatHub(CollectionService<Profile> profileService, CollectionService<User> userService)
    {
     // This constructor is being called
      _profileService = profileService;
      _userService = userService;
    }

    [Authorize]
    public async Task UpdateProfile()
    {
      // I have put a breakpoint here but it is not being hit
      await Clients.All.SendAsync("Test");
    }
  }
}
```

The React front end appears to be waiting for the connection correctly, as well as invoking the method correctly, but it's not working!

The pertinent code from my React provider looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();

      const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
        .withUrl('http://localhost:3010/chathub', {accessTokenFactory: () => accessToken})
        .build();

      await connection.start();
      setConnected(true);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  })()
}, [isAuthenticated]);

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    if(connected && user) {
      // this code is being hit, but the method on the back end is not
      await connection?.send('UpdateProfile');
    }
  })()
}, [connected, user])
```

Does anyone know why this might be? I have tried a lowercase method name in the call, but this doesn't help.

Comment: What is the error message?Are your sure you have get the token correctly?

Answer (score 0):

put  `[Authorize]` attribute on top of your `ChatHub`  class. If you didn't configure any default authorization scheme on Startup, you need to include an authorization scheme  like this

```
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class ChatHub: Hub 
    {
          //...
    }
```

*Note: When I am working with SignalR I convert my DTOs to JSON String and pass them to the server, maybe you need to do that for the function that have an argument.
like this :

```
     public void FunctionName(string  dtoString)
     {
        
        var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectDto>(dtoString);
        //Do something with my DTO
        
      }
```

and also pass back objects as JSON String to the client like this

```
    var resultString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ResultObject, new 
    JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });
    Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ClientFunction", resultString  );
```

token in SignalR is sent in query, so you need to read them from query and put them on the header.

```
  services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidIssuer = [Issuer Site],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes([YOUR SECRET KEY STRING]))
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var path = context.Request.Path;
                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/chathub"))
                    {
                        
                        context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new[] { $"Bearer {accessToken}" });
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

Let me know if you have any trouble.
Hope it works!